# Swift: Layout issues for GADBannerView with different size classes

Tags: ios, swift, gadbannerview

This question may be a duplicate but I cannot seem to find an answer for it.

I have a 320 x 50 `GADBannerView` centered at the bottom of the view controller. When loaded the `bannerView` changes size from the specified width: 320 & height: 50 which I have tried to override with the following code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    self.bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.minX, y: view.frame.maxY, width: 320, height: 50)
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```

but this is causing the banner to load 1/3 of the way up the page on the iPhone 7 and 6, to load to the bottom righthand side of the viewcontroller on the iPhone 5s and SE, to not appear at all on the 6 & 7 plus and to appear off centre to the left on iPad models.

Constraints:
[image]

I have tried using the vary for traits feature in Xcode 8 but this seems to set the constraints on every size class instead of the isolated size class.

Is there a way to get the `GADBannerView` a fixed width:320, height: 50 and centered at the bottom of the view controller for all sizes and models?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov:  Is it possible display different Ads on each recurring items?